# Efficient way to refer to the type-name of the iterator without typing the entire container definition?

Tags: c++, boost, containers, boost-iterators

Is there a more efficient way to refer to the typename of a container's iterator than typing

```
std::unordered_map<keyclass, valueclass>::iterator
```

every time I need the iterator?

Of course, there is

```
typedef boost::unordered_map<keyclass, valueclass>::iterator classitr
```

but introducing typedef's for every container does not strike me as very readable code.
Being new to C++, and assuming that one usually has a reference to the container they want to use - is there something along the lines of

```
Container<KeyClass, ValueClass> x;

x::iterator_type i
```

or any other obvious shortcut that I am missing?

Comment: If you use the [algorithms library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) you won't have to refer to the iterator types as much.

Comment: @PeterWood I am still very much thinking in C terms, so I have noticed all these functions, but never used them much. I will give that a try. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one of the reasons why C++11 introduced the new meaning of the `auto` keyword:

```
auto it = vec.begin();
```

The compiler will work out the type of `it` from the initializer in a similar manner to template type deduction.

Pre-C++11, the usual approach was to use `typedef`s as you have suggested. It can often be most useful to `typedef` the container and then give everything relative to that:

```
typedef std::unordered_map<key, value> map;
map m;
map::iterator = m.begin();
```

You can give a more meaningful name to your `typedef` that describes exactly what kind of `map` it is. For example, if you had a map from names to phone numbers, you could call it `phone_map` and the iterator would be `phone_map::iterator`.

<sup>`auto` is also a useful tool for perfect forwarding</sup>

Comment: Thank you. I am not completely up to speed with what the C++11 standard will bring - so I didn't think of that. Is there any non C++11 way? (sorry for my previous short answer, I did not know that hitting enter will submit my comment)

Comment: @Stefan Not "will bring", but "has brought". Using `typedef`s was the typical solution pre-C++11.

Comment: @sftrabbit: "Will bring" to his code when he makes the switch. Not everybody is using C++11. I for one will not bring it into our production code quite yet.

Comment: Typedef'ing the container seems quite nice; I haven't thought of that.  And thank you for confirming that there is no "clean" Pre-C++11 solution similar to what I was hoping for. As for C++11, since my knowledge with the new standard is far from intimate, and the support matrix on the Apache wiki makes me dizzy, I think I stick with learning C++ first, and then making the step to C++11, when I see its advantages first-hand. Your answer has given me the first instance of that. :) Thank you for a great and detailed answer.

Answer (score 2):

In C++11 you can use `decltype` to get a type from a variable.

Write:

```
std::unordered_map<keyclass, valueclass> m;
decltype(m)::iterator it = m.begin();
```

Of course, if you're in C++1, then you can also just write:

```
std::unordered_map<keyclass, valueclass> m;
auto it = m.begin();
```

Comment: Thank you - decltype seems to do exactly what I was hoping for in my question. One more reason to look forward to making the step to C++11. :) 
The knowledge in SO is amazing.